# jars puzzle question ,Initial configuration and final configuration in ruby

Tags: ruby

Suppose there are 3 jars with some maximum capacity, Let it be 8 litres, 5 litres, 3 litres.

Initial configuration is 8 litres, 0 litres, 0 litres, and the final configuration be 4 litres, 4 litres, 0 litres.

The program should produce a sequence of operations to reach the final configuration from initial configuration, or return a message if no path exists.

Your program should be able to work out the steps for any initial and final config as given by the User.

i am totally confused..
please give me any suggestion..........

[puzzle output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDpoo.png)

Comment: Hi. What are the rules of the game? Which operation can be made? Please add more info to the problem.

Comment: Why haven't you responded to @Daniele's question?

Comment: At this time there are 4 votes to close the question. If you don't want it closed (which requires just one more vote) you need to clarify your question. I think you need something like the second sentence of my answer (which you are welcome to borrow), assuming my understanding is correct. I've seen enough puzzles about shifting liquids among three bottles that I'm pretty confident that I see what you are trying to do.

Comment: The question is on hold, but its not too late to fix it. Who knows, if you clarify the question the hold may be lifted.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not an answer but an extended comment. (No upvotes please.)

I assume that transfers are such that if some or all of the contents of Jar A are transferred to Jar B, after the transfer has been completed jar A will be empty or jar B will be full.

Here's a start (not a solution).

```
class Jars
  attr_accessor :content
  attr_reader :capacity, :target

  def initialize(capacity, content, target)
    @capacity, @content, @target = capacity, content, target
  end

  def transfer_to(other_jar)
     if self.content <= other_jar.capacity - other_jar.content
       # jar self is emptied
       other_jar.content += self.content
       self.content = 0
     else
       # other_jar becomes full
       self.content -= other_jar.capacity - other_jar.content
       other_jar.content = other_jar.capacity
     end
  end
end
```

```
def success?(*jars)
  jars.all? { |jar| jar.content == jar.target }
end
```

```
jar8 = Jars.new(8, 8, 4)
  #=> #<Jars:0x000057c7edc841e8 @capacity=8, @content=8> 
jar5 = Jars.new(5, 0, 4)
  #=> #<Jars:0x000057c7ede176e0 @capacity=5, @content=0> 
jar3 = Jars.new(3, 0, 0)
  #=> #<Jars:0x000057c7ede422a0 @capacity=3, @content=0>
```

```
jar8.content #=> 8
jar5.content #=> 0
jar3.content #=> 0

success?(jar3, jar5, jar8) #=> false
```

```
jar8.transfer_to(jar3)
jar8.content #=> 5
jar5.content #=> 0
jar3.content #=> 3

success?(jar3, jar5, jar8) #=> false
```

```
jar3.transfer_to(jar5)
jar8.content #=> 5
jar5.content #=> 3
jar3.content #=> 0

success?(jar3, jar5, jar8) #=> false
```

and so on. Can you come up with an algorithm that results in `success?(jar3, jar5, jar8) #=> true`?

Comment: You put in the work to solve a problem you're gonna get an upvote. It's the rules! 